# Sync validation on a radiogroup (v6)

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

How can I display sync-validation errors for my radiogroup when using the v6 version of redux-form? One option would be to create multiple renderField functions, in which only one (the last one) would display the errors. I currently have it setup like this:

```
const renderField = ({ input, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <span>
    <input
      {...input}
    />
    {
      touched &&
      error &&
        <div>
          {error}
        </div>
    }
  </span>
);

// Form-component
// I loop trough multiple values

<Field
  type="radio"
  component={renderField}
  id={`${field.name}-${value}`}
  value={value}
  name={field.name}
/>

<Field
  type="radio"
  id={`${field.name}-${value}`}
  value={value}
  name={field.name}
/>
```

In this way, the errors get presented multiple times (for each value). I could pass an extra prop when it is the last value, to enable the errors for just that field. Although that would work, it feels kinda nasty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question. Another option would be to write a component that was just in charge of rendering errors.

```
const renderError = ({ meta: { touched, error } }) =>
  touched && error && <div>{error}</div>
```

Then, after you had rendered your radio buttons, you could do a:

```
<Field name={field.name} component={renderError}/>
```